# Spring Webflow, the ID and version get stripped

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I recently came across a strange error with Spring Webflow and I can't seem to find the problem, and noone ever experienced that, it seems.

When starting my flow I load from the database an object which the user will then modify in the flow.
As the object is loaded, every property is correctly binded: while debugging the on-entry function, the object has all properties set. After that, though, when the view has been rendered, the object's "id" and "version" fields suddenly become null, so `<form:hidden path="id" />` or `<form:hidden path="version" />` do not display anything.

I don't know where to start and I don't want to put here useless code, so if you need some part of my code just ask.

Additional informations:

I also tried to forcefully modify those fields by using `<form:input path="id" />` and trying to manually put some values inside and submitting the form, with no luck.

**Important update**
It seems that this problem happens with every "complex" object, let's say that MyForm has another class in it, called B. If that B contains only basic types such as Integer and String, they are correctly stored and retrieved with their id and version field, if that B has other kind of object fields in it (a C class), then their id and version disappears.

Excerpt of the flow configuration that interests the view. Please note that every data is viewed correctly in  the form except the id and version fields.

FLOW:

```
<input name="idObj" />
<decision-state id="createOrEdit">
    <if test="idObj== null" then="newObj" else="modObj" />
</decision-state>
...
<action-state id="modObj">
    <evaluate expression="Search.findOne(idObj)" result="flowScope.form"/>
    <transition to="object" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="object" view="flow.object" model="form">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="handler.prepare(flowScope.form)"/>
    </on-entry>
    <!-- transitions omitted -->
</view-state>
```

VIEW:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="form" cssClass="form form-horizontal">
    <form:input path="id" />
    <form:input path="version" />
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
</form:form>
```

HANDLER:

```
public void prepare(MyForm form) {

    int codType = form.getFormType().getId();
    FormType type = service.findOne(codType);

    form.setFormType(type); // This is here for JPA to save correctly the instance
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    requestContext.getViewScope().put("typeList", typeService.findAll());
}
```

Comment: Show how view is configured in flow xml and commandName you are using in view.

Comment: Edited the message. Note that the whole form and flow is working perfectly (since I can save new instances) except for the ID and VERSION fields

Comment: Did you try with cout as: <c:out value="${form.id}"/> in the view which is a litmus to see if value is really bound with form.

Comment: Yes, I did, and nothing shows up... It seems that after the object is processed and passed to the view the values are removed. I also tried to put some values manually, both placing the fields in the view and setting the value in the controllers, but the result is still the same: value is null no matter what

Comment: Then my suspicion would be on prepare method of handler. Can you post it's code as well?

Comment: It does nothing but set a list that will populate a select item, based on a parameter present in the form. Anyway I'm posting the code

Comment: In prepare method can you check if Id and version are set?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the original post, when I debug that function all the variables are correctly set, plus I debugged all the accesses to the setId() function and also debugged the read/modify of the id variable, but the function never gets called and the variable itself never gets modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after three days of hitting my head hard on the desk I discovered what follows:

In order for Webflow to work with any kind of custom form, it has to implement the `Serializable` interface, and my form object actually did it. **But** the object from which it inherited the `id` and `version` fields **did not**, so all the object-related properties were correctly stored, but not the inherited ones which weren't serialized.

So, in short, to make it work I just put the `implements Serializable` in the base database object class: `public class BaseDTO implements Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you for solving this. I wasted 3 hrs on it before I found your answer instead of 3 days :)